# Selecting polygons within others that share a boundary

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, canada, select-by-location

Thanks in advance for any help. I have a feature class in ArcGIS 10.2 with 455 polygons,they are municipal boundaries. We use it to determine permissions for users in another application and it's based on sharing a boundary. So, for example, Muni A touches Muni B and C, so Muni A's rights will be:

-Muni A

-All towns within

-Muni B

--All towns within

-Muni C

--All towns within

It's simple enough to select by location to determine the municipalities that share a boundary, however, I cannot seem to take that selection and do another based on those results to select the town polygons within B and C. Second to that, can you possibly script this to make it iterative so I can generate shp files for said permissions automatically?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in model builder. So you have your selection on the Municipal boundaries (A,B & C). Use that selection to select all towns. This will select all towns in A,B & C. Clear selection on municipals, select A by attribute then do a select by location but *removing* the selection from the towns, this will leave you selected towns in B & C.

The assumption behind this method is that towns fall entirely within your Municipal polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I pulled the attached script from the ESRI 10.2 Help section on [Select Layer By Location (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000072000000://).  You can see how they do an initial select based on location followed by subsetting by attributes.  You can replace the select by attributes by a select by location and specify `SUBSET_SELECTION`.

```
# Name: ExtactFeaturesByLocationAndAttribute.py
# Description: Extract features to a new feature class based on a Location and an attribute query

# Import arcpy and set path to data
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "c:/data/mexico.gdb"

# Make a layer and select cities which overlap the chihuahua polygon
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('cities', 'cities_lyr') 
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('cities_lyr', 'intersect', 'chihuahua')

# Within the previous selection sub-select cities which have population > 10,000
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('cities_lyr', 
                                        'SUBSET_SELECTION', '"population" > 10000')

# If features matched criteria write them to a new feature class
matchcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management('cities_lyr').getOutput(0)) 
if matchcount == 0:
    print('no features matched spatial and attribute criteria')
else:
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('cities_lyr', 'chihuahua_10000plus')
    print('{0} cities that matched criteria written to {0}'.format(
                                                  matchcount, chihuahua_10000plus))
```